# Python cx_Oracle missing SELECT keyword

Tags: python, insert, cx-oracle

I'm woking on Python cx_Oracle INSERT INTO and I'm having an error which I can't find

My code can successfully connect to Oracle server

My code is

```
curs = connect.cursor()
number1 = input("Input number = ")
name = input("Input name = ")
address = input("Input address")
date = input("Input date in DD-MON-YYYY format = ")
number2 = input("Input number = ")
statement = "INSERT INTO table (:number1,:name,:address,:date,:number2) VALUES (:x,:n,:a,to_date(:d, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),:y)"
curs.execute(statement,{'x':number1, 'n':name, 'a':address, 'd':date, 'y':number2})
curs.commit()
```

I have tried my inputs with

```
1234, John, Elm Street,01-JAN-2000, 5678
```

The error said

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

I'm guessing the error is probably from the date format but I can't quite find where the exact error lies in my code

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Will you please give full traceback?

Answer (score 2):

'table' is a reserved word, so I'm not sure you can use as an actual table to query.

In your statement :number1 should be number1, :name should be name and so on.